# ASP.NET Core 2 Migrations don't work on new machine with empty database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, migration

I created a ASP.NET Core 2 project, created some migrations along the way, and pushed the code up to a repository.

Today, I pulled the code to another computer I have for development, the database was obviously not created on the new machine so I created a empty database locally to match the connection string.

Now, when trying to run the code "dotnet ef database update" I get this error:

> An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class
>   'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
>   One or more errors occurred. **(Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.)**
>   Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. Add an
>   implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the
>   project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for
>   additional patterns supported at design time.

Please keep in mind that any "dotnet ef" command I run I have the same error, I tried deleting all the migrations and creating a new one using the "dotnet ef migrations add InitialDb" command, but I still get this error.

I am using Identity in my project and I believe it has to do with this error: (Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.)

The commands run without any problem on the machine I initially started to develop the application.

I tried Update-Database from PM with the same result.

Here is an image illustrating the problem:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I had a seeder in the Startup class that was seeding an admin user in case it did not exist.

Because the table did not exist the seeder was failing on each command because it was in the Startup class and was executing all the time.

This issue can be closed.